# How do I find the number of peaks from smart meter customer's load profile?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, cluster-analysis, data-analysis

I plotted the customer's electricity load profile from smart meter data. The data is time-series and recorded every 15 mins. I want to find the number of peaks(those peak(s) which are significant) of the customer using his/her load profile. Can you suggest the methodology to do the same? This question is related to the electricity consumption data of the consumers.

Answer (score 1):

The standard methodology would *not* be clustering.

Instead, use kernel density estimation to smoothen the data, then count the local maxima.

Whether it will work for your data: we don't know your data.